# custom tableviewcell error

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I want to work with a custom tableview Cell.

I have productTableViewCell classes. In my xib I defined a lblProduct, on this label I want to show my product names. I have synthesized it and connected it properly in my xib.

Now in my other class with my tableview in it. I do this. All my product are in the arrayProducts.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    productTableviewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"productTableviewCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (UIView *view in views) {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {   
                cell = (productTableviewCell*)view;
            }
        }
    }
    NSString *cellValue = [arrayProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"value: %@", cellValue);
    cell.lblProduct.text = cellValue;

    //  NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.lblProduct.text = [info objectForKey:@"Pro_naam"];

    return cell;

}
```

But when i run it. I get this error.

> 2012-01-30 10:02:40.032 MamzelBestelling2[12923:f803] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not
>   key value coding-compliant for the key lblProduct.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x13c0052 0x1551d0a 0x13bff11 0x9b7032 0x928f7b 0x928eeb 0x943d60 0x23691a 0x13c1e1a 0x132b821 0x23546e
>   0x237010 0x4d9f 0xb0e0f 0xb1589 0x9cdfd 0xab851 0x56301 0x13c1e72
>   0x1d6a92d 0x1d74827 0x1cfafa7 0x1cfcea6 0x1cfc580 0x13949ce 0x132b670
>   0x12f74f6 0x12f6db4 0x12f6ccb 0x12a9879 0x12a993e 0x17a9b 0x2148
>   0x20a5) terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto;
>   currently objective-c (gdb)

Anybody can help ?

Answer (score 0):

you don't really need to store it into a NSString first. Try doing it this way:

```
cell.lblProduct.text = [arrayProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Also make sure that you have done the `@property` and `@synthesize` properly and connected them up in your CustomCell xib

Comment: I found the problem. I got a wrong identifier in my custom tableview cell :)

Answer (score 0):

If you created CustomTableViewCell, you have to set a tag for "lblProduct", say 100. And then 
do

```
UILabel *label=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
NSString *cellValue = [arrayProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"value: %@", cellValue);
lblProduct.text = cellValue;

return cell;
```

It will work!!!!

For more information http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1